# ctools with panels colon issue IIS

Tags: ajax, panels, chaos-tool-suite

When using **Panels** module I have noticed that one of the ajax calls is creating an url with colon inside :

For Example :

```
dev-www.redbusbingo.com/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_c

%3A = :
```

The problem is that iis Dont know how to Handle ":/" , or to say this colon in the end of string

This case break the site with error 500 .

```
500 Error Case : "dev-www.redbusbingo.com/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_c" ( Colon at the end Before "/")
```

Good Case :

```
 "dev-www.redbusbingo.com/panels/ajax/editor/select-content/panel_c" ( NO colon at the end Before the "/")
```

Is there any way to replace this colons ?

Just to say i have reported this bug to Microsoft and they said that this a security issue and because of that they will not allow colons in the url .

Currently i can't work on my site because of this error and my iis ,
Please assist me with this .

Thanks
Haniel

Answer (score 1):

I've finally succeded in correcting this bug, by modifying directly the Panels module. I'll publish a patch on panel's forum on drupal's site. Here's the solution :

In the file /sites/all/modules/panels/plugins/display_renderers/panels_renderer_editor.class.php, you have to change get_url() function (line 505), replace this:

```
 $url = 'panels/ajax/' . $this->plugin['name'] . '/' . $command . '/' . $this->display->cache_key;
```

by this

```
 if (variable_get('clean_url', FALSE))
  $url = '?q=';

$url .= 'panels/ajax/' . $this->plugin['name'] . '/' . $command . '/' . $this->display->cache_key;
```

As you maybe know the problem is caused by cleans Url, so it works without the fix if u disable it. But if you want to keep cleans url, apply the fix, it forces all ajax requests to be without cleans urls

PS: Thank you to [MPD♦](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/835/mpd) who deleted my previous answer where i put a link to azure forum which was a possible way to solve the problem.